# How to get web page title using html parser

Tags: html-parsing

How can I get the title of a web page for a given URL using an HTML parser? Is it possible to get the title using regular expressions? I would prefer to use an HTML parser.

I am working in the Java Eclipse IDE.

I have tried using the following code, but was unsuccessful.

Any ideas?

Thank in advance!

```
import org.htmlparser.Node;

import org.htmlparser.Parser;

import org.htmlparser.util.NodeList;

import org.htmlparser.util.ParserException;

import org.htmlparser.tags.TitleTag;    

public class TestHtml {

public static void main(String... args) {
    Parser parser = new Parser();     
    try {
        parser.setResource("http://www.yahoo.com/");
        NodeList list = parser.parse(null);
        Node node = list.elementAt(0);

        if (node instanceof TitleTag) {
           TitleTag title = (TitleTag) node;


            System.out.println(title.getText());

        }

    } catch (ParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: [You cannot parse HTML or XML with regular expresisons.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your (redefined) question, the problem is that you only check the first node `Node node = list.elementAt(0);` while you should iterate over the list to find the title (which is not the first). You could also use a `NodeFilter` for your `parse()` to only return the `TitleTag` and then the title would be in the first and you wouldn't have to iterate.

Comment: ::Yep..I know But still I couldn't find the way should I follow to filter the TitleTag!

Any idea..?? thnx!

Comment: Never used that library but must be classic... something like new NodeFilter() { public boolean accept(Node node) { return node instanceof TitleTag; } }

Comment: :: Thank alot bro..got the result based on your answer..have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Well - assuming you're using java, but there is the equivalent in most of the languages - you can use a SAX parser (such as TagSoup which transform any html to xhtml) and in your handler you can do :

```
public class MyHandler extends org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler {
    boolean readTitle = false;
    StringBuilder title = new StringBuilder();

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if(localName.equals("title") {
            readTitle = true;
        }
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
            throws SAXException {
        if(localName.equals("title") {
            readTitle = false;
        }
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        if(readTitle) title.append(new String(ch, start, length));
    }
}
```

and you use it in your parser (example with tagsoup) :

```
org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser parser = new Parser();
MyHandler handler = new MyHander();
parser.setContentHandler(handler);
parser.parse(an input stream to your html file);
return handler.title.toString();
```

Comment: I have tried out with following code segment.But still I couldn't get the result.



public class TestParser{
  public static void main(String... args) {
     try{
         Parser parser = new Parser();
         parser.setResource("http://www.youtube.com");
         NodeList list = parser.parse(null);
         Node node = list.elementAt(0);

         if(node instanceof TitleTag){

                 TitleTag title = ( TitleTag) node ;
                 System.out.println(title.getText());
         }
         

     }

    catch(ParserException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

Comment: you should put this in your question and define which language and which librarie(s) you use (and maybe add the corresponding tags), it would be more efficient to have an answer if the question is less vague...

Comment: ::I have edited my question and If you can give any idea or correction it would better for me..thanx!

Comment: added an other answer that correspond to the newly defined question.

Answer (score 1):

BTW there is already a very simple title extract that ships with HTMLParser. You can use that : http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/samples.html

The method to run it is (from within the HtmlParser code base) : 
Run :

`bin/parser http://website_url TITLE`

or run

`java -jar <path to htmlparser.jar> http://website_url TITLE`

or from your code call the method

`org.htmlparser.Parser.main(String[] args)`

with the parameters `new String[]  {"<website url>", "TITLE"}`

Answer (score 0):

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Smart you don't want to use the Regex.

To use an HTML parser, we need to know which *language* you're using.  Since you say you're "on eclipse", I'm going to assume Java.

Take a look at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-domjava/ for a description, overview, and various viewpoints.

Answer (score 0):

This will be very easy using HTMLAgilityPack you only need to get responce of httpRequest in the form of string.

```
    String response=httpRequest.getResponseString(); // this may have a few changes or no 
HtmlDocument doc= new HtmlDocument();
doc.loadHtml(response);
HtmlNode node =doc.DocumentNode.selectSingleNode("//title"); // this line will fetch title tage from whole html document and return collection could iterate
node.innerText; //gives you the title of the page
```

**helloWorld  node.innerText contains helloWorld**

OR

```
String response=httpRequest.getResponseString(); // this may have a few changes or no 
HtmlDocument doc= new HtmlDocument();
doc.loadHtml(response);

HtmlNode node =doc.DocumentNode.selectSingleNode("//head");// this additional will get head which is a single node in html than get title from head's childrens
HtmlNode node =node.selectSingleNode("//title"); // this line will fetch title tage from whole html document and return collection could iterate


node.innerText; //gives you the title of the page
```